# Fargate vs Codebuild for running end to end test cases on a serverless application

Tags: amazon-web-services, e2e-testing, continuous-deployment, aws-codebuild, aws-fargate

We have a serverless application that we are writing end-to-end test cases for. End-to-end tests have their own repository. They are going to be long-running, Yes. (I hear Fargate is cheaper).

Our CI/CD pipeline is written using CDK and uses CodePipeline and Codebuild.

What is a better choice for running end-to-end test cases in this case: Fargate or Codebuild ? and Why?

Comment: How long is "long-running", 10 minutes, 10 hours?

Comment: @Marcin: Thanks for your response. It should be a couple hours

Comment: How many hours would you expect to spend running this per month?

Comment: We haven't decided if we will be running nightly builds yet. If we end up running nightly builds then close to 40-50 hours. If not, then barely 10-20 hours @jingx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did a quick rundown on the cost difference between [CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/pricing/) and [Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/pricing/):
Assuming the `general1.large` instance type in CodeBuild, 40 build hours would cost:

$0.02 x 60 x 40 = $48

`general1.large` provides 8 vCPUs, and 15 GB RAM, so an equivalent Fargate instance would cost:

$0.04048 x 8 x 40 + $0.004445 x 15 x 40 = $12.9536 + $2.67 = $15.6

Give the $32 difference per month, I'd stay with CodeBuild.  It's doable to hook into CodePipeline a custom job worker running in Fargate, but I suspect it'll cost a lot more than $32 in terms of development and maintenance overhead.